# Sharing the reputation

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I have seen many new users who are actually very impressive and most of them seems to bring many new ways of thinking and perspectives. 
Older the users are more they have reputation and they have no practicle use for it.

*So my question is...*

Can we have a better rewarding system (Something like a community recognition award for new users)
This way we can encourage them and keep them here at Buddhism SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@CrabBucket](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1829/254)

> If someone decided to give away a big chunk of their rep it would undermine this a bit.

The real world works like that though: if I trust someone and they trust someone else then I might believe their assessment of trustworthiness (you do that if you trust employees of trusted institutions).

> Just a thought

It's a good thought.

Another idea  might be that on CodeReview.SE they have [some kind of topic on their meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) for proposing good answers. For example we could have a "Best of 2015" topic on our meta, in which we invite people to submit (as an answers) a short list of their favourite posts from the last year.

That needn't be specifically/exclusively for new users (but it could be if that were a good idea, e.g. "Good questions or answers by new users").

And there could be bounty associated with that.

Another benefit is that I'd be able to review some posts which other people thought were especially good, and perhaps read their explanation for why they think they're especially good/useful.

Comment: "Best of 2015" that's a very good idea!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the input.

We already have a system that regulates a users overall contribution and question/answer-quality. That is the voting-system. One can upvote, downvote and choose a best answer.

Even if we wanted to make changes in that system, it is out of our hands.

All other Stack Exchange Sites have the same voting-system, so I think that is how it will be. It works really good and it is the foundation for defining the quality of a users contribution and the content-quality on a SE.

If you still would like to implement that new system, you can contact the [Stack Exchange Support and Administration](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and give the proposal to them.

Comment: If you want to propose new software features you should probably do that by posting on meta.stackexchange.com -- see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request for some examples (and note that there are 20,000 of them).

Comment: @ChrisW. Great, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only other thing that could be done is for (higher) rep users to put bounties on certain questions to encourage answering and spread the reputation around a bit.

I personally think that's a reasonable idea but really is going to be up to the individual users. The downside is the reputation is a signal to the rest of the community. It indicates trust in a particular user and let's people know that this user has a history of good quality answers with maybe a bit of community building thrown in. If someone decided to give away a big chunk of their rep it would undermine this a bit.

That said it could be a bit of Dana as well. Just a thought

Comment: Yes bounties are rare here!

Answer (score 1):

Giving a Dhammic answer. Even if shared, its not possible to actually share merits.

Such things would even force certain kind of trade and be not well for its community function as it would even faster run corrupt.